# Unknown tag error

Tags: spring, jsp

For my jsp file, I have an unknown tag error for the line that begins `Class.forName...`, followed by a invalid location of text error for `"org.springframework....;". I don't understand why.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
prefix="springForm"%>
<%@ Class.forName("org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"); %>
<html>
```

Comment: That's Java code, not a directive. Unrelated, but man, `"springForm"` is a heck of a long prefix to spew all over your page. And... scriptlets?!

Comment: @Dave Newton I don't understand your java code and not a directive stuff. I'm doing something similar I found on the web so I thought it should work

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `<%@ %>` is for page directives, not Java code.

Comment: I understand, but why does this guy do it: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0d4935/inserted-data-into-table-through-jsp/

Comment: Look at the jsp and make correction at  `<%@ Class.forName("org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"); %>`. Shouldn't it be `<% Class.forName("org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"); %>`?

Comment: And, if you understand, then it'd make sense to look up something regarding JSP, page directives, scriptlets, etc.

Comment: I see what I was doing, I misread the example with the `@`.